# Chrome floped image background stuck issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, css, background

I am having a weird problem with Chrome. 
If I flop an image using -webkit-transform, show another div on top it and then hide the div, part of the image is showed in background as some sort of ghost image.

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/fahadnabbasi/d4erm/

The problem is only in chrome.

I am using Mac OS X and latest version of chrome for mac.

Please please held me as I am out of options here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you remove  `-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);` the issue no longer appears
try instead

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); 
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 28%;
```

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/JHFQV/

Comment: yes but I need to flip/flop the images so -webkit-transform is required

Comment: try my update. it performs almost the same effect without matrix transformation (and no ghost image appears)

Comment: its cool, it works but how can i flop and flip an image at the same time? I mean in matrix i have the two different values but not here.

Comment: what do you exactly mean? rotateX is performing alone the transformation

Comment: yes but there are two transformations either an image can be in Flipped state(Horizontal), or Flopped state(Vertical) or both flipped and flopped states

Comment: ok you may use instead rotate3D and specify the value for x,y and z axis all together: see http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/ or just chain rotateX, rotateY and rotateZ

Comment: woow you are the man F. Calderan. Thanks a lot, you saved a lot of my time :)